# Given the angle $BOB'$ and the points $A \in (OB)$, $A' \in (OB')$ prove a general identity in this angle.

Tags: geometry

Consider the angle $BOB'$ and the points $A \in (OB)$, $A' \in (OB')$. I have to show that the following identities are true:

$$\hspace{5cm} \vec{OM} = m \dfrac{1-n}{1-mn} \vec{OA} + n \dfrac{1-m}{1-mn} \vec{OA'} \hspace{5cm} (1)$$

$$\hspace{5.3cm} \vec{ON} = m \dfrac{n - 1}{n - m} \vec{OA} + n \dfrac{m - 1}{m - n} \vec{OA'} \hspace{5.3cm} (2)$$

where we have:

$$\hspace{5cm} \{ M \} = AB' \cap A'B \hspace{5cm} (3)$$

$$\hspace{5cm} \{ N \} = AA' \cap BB' \hspace{5cm} (4)$$

$$\hspace{5.5cm} \vec{OB} = m \vec{OA} \hspace{5.5cm} (5)$$

$$\hspace{5.5cm} \vec{OB'} = n \vec{OA'} \hspace{5.5cm} (6)$$

I decided to start with proving $(1)$. I started from the left-hand side:

$$m \dfrac{1-n}{1-mn} \vec{OA} + n \dfrac{1-m}{1-mn} \vec{OA'} = $$

$$ = \dfrac{m \vec{OA} - mn \vec{OA}}{1-mn} + \dfrac{n \vec{OA'} - mn \vec{OA'}}{1-mn} $$

$$ = \dfrac{m \vec{OA} - mn \vec{OA} + n \vec{OA'} - mn \vec{OA'}}{1-mn} $$

Because of the given equalities $(5)$ and $(6)$ we can write:

$$ = \dfrac{\vec{OB} - mn \vec{OA} + \vec{OB'} - mn \vec{OA'}}{1-mn} $$

$$ = \dfrac{\vec{OB} + \vec{OB'} - mn (\vec{OA} + \vec{OA'})}{1-mn} $$

But this is as far as I got, I don't know how to prove that what I wrote above is equal to $\vec{OM}$.

Answer (score 1):

As $M$ is the intersection point of lines $AB'$ and $A'B$, there exist two real numbers $s$ and $t$ such that:
$$
\vec{OM}=(1-s)\,\vec{OA'}+s\,\vec{OB}=(1-t)\,\vec{OA}+t\,\vec{OB'}.
$$
Substitute here $\vec{OB}=m\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB'}=n\vec{OA'}$:
$$
\vec{OM}=(1-s)\,\vec{OA'}+ms\,\vec{OA}=(1-t)\,\vec{OA}+nt\,\vec{OA'}
$$
and find by comparison $s$, $t$ as functions of $m$, $n$:
$$
\cases{
1-s = nt \\
\\
ms = 1-t \\
}\quad\implies
\cases{
\displaystyle s = {1-n\over1-mn} \\
\\
\displaystyle t = {1-m\over1-mn} \\
}.
$$

An analogous computation can be repeated for $\vec{ON}$.